# Insert space after the second or third capital letter python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing addresses. Some are formatted correctly like `481 Rogers Rd York ON`. Others have a space missing between the city quandrant and the city name, for example: `101 9 Ave SWCalgary AB` or even possibly: `101 9 Ave SCalgary AB`, where `SW` refers to south west and `S` to south.

I'm trying to find a regex that will add a space between second and third capital letters if they are followed by lowercase letters, or if there are only 2 capitals followed by lower case, add a space between the first and second.

So far, I've found that `([A-Z]{2,3}[a-z])` will match the situation correctly, but I can't figure out how to look back into it and sub at position 2 or 3. Ideally, I'd like to use an index to split the match at `[-2:]` but I can't figure out how to do this.

I found that `re.findall('(?<=[A-Z][A-Z])[A-Z][a-z].+', '101 9 Ave SWCalgary AB')`
will return the last part of the string and I could use a look forward regex to find the start and then join them but this seems very inefficient.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
df['Test'] = df['Test'].str.replace(r'\b([A-Z]{1,2})([A-Z][a-z])', r'\1 \2')
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ji9KOP/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `([A-Z]{1,2})` - Capturing group 1 (later referred with `\1` from the replacement pattern): one or two uppercase letters
- `([A-Z][a-z])` - Capturing group 2 (later referred with `\2` from the replacement pattern): an uppercase letter + a lowercase one.

If you want to *specifically match **city quadrants***, you may use a bit more specific regex:

```
df['Test'] = df['Test'].str.replace(r'\b([NS][EW]|[NESW])([A-Z][a-z])', r'\1 \2')
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ji9KOP/2). Here, `[NS][EW]|[NESW]` matches `N` or `S` that are followed with `E` or `W`, or a single `N`, `E`, `S` or `W`.

Pandas demo:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test':['481 Rogers Rd York ON', 
'101 9 Ave SWCalgary AB',
'101 9 Ave SCalgary AB']})
>>> df['Test'].str.replace(r'\b([A-Z]{1,2})([A-Z][a-z])', r'\1 \2')
0      481 Rogers Rd York ON
1    101 9 Ave SW Calgary AB
2     101 9 Ave S Calgary AB
Name: Test, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
([A-Z]{1,2})(?=[A-Z][a-z])
```

to capture the first (or first and second) capital letters, and then use lookahead for a capital letter followed by a lowercase letter. Then, replace with the first group and a space:

```
re.sub(r'([A-Z]{1,2})(?=[A-Z][a-z])', r'\1 ', str)
```

https://regex101.com/r/TcB4Ph/1